# how do i expand the enter button to bridge all 3 rows? i.e should be extended to sit under both '0' '.' and 'Del'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, numpad

I'm using tkinter to create my first GUI and i have reached a problem. How do I expand the 'enter' button of the numpad (which opens when you click a empty box) to cover the empty space currently there?

How do I designate the opening position of the numpad?

Additionally if anyone has a shorter/faster way to code this i would be interested as to how it can be done as whilst speed isn't extremely necessary for my project, it is always nice to have.

The code is as follows below:

```python3
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

def enumerate_row_column(iterable, num_cols):
    for idx, item in enumerate(iterable):
        row = idx // num_cols
        col = idx % num_cols
        yield row,col,item

class NumpadEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Entry.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>',self.numpadEntry)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>',self.numpadExit)
        self.edited = False
    def numpadEntry(self,event):
        if self.edited == False:
            print("You Clicked on me")
            self['bg']= '#ffffcc'
            self.edited = True
            new = numPad(self)
        else:
            self.edited = False
    def numpadExit(self,event):
        self['bg']= '#ffffff'

class numPad(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,master=None,textVariable=None):
        self.top = Toplevel(master=master)
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.ok)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.master = master
       
    def createWidgets(self):
        btn_list = ['1',  '2',  '3', '4',  '5',  '6', '7',  '8',  '0', '0',  '.',  'Del', 'Enter']
        # create and position all buttons with a for-loop
        btn = []
        # Use custom generator to give us row/column positions
        for r,c,label in enumerate_row_column(btn_list,3):
            # partial takes care of function and argument
            cmd = lambda x = label: self.click(x)
            # create the button
            cur = Button(self.top, text=label, width=5, height=3, command=cmd)
            # position the button
            cur.grid(row=r, column=c)                                              
            btn.append(cur)
           
    def click(self,label):
        print(label)
        if label == 'Del':
            currentText = self.master.get()
            self.master.delete(0, END)
            self.master.insert(0, currentText[:-1])
        elif label == 'Enter':
            self.ok()
        else:
            currentText = self.master.get()
            self.master.delete(0, END)
            self.master.insert(0, currentText+label)
    def ok(self):
        self.top.destroy()
        self.top.master.focus()

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        self.textEntryVar1 = StringVar()
        self.e1 = NumpadEntry(self,textvariable=self.textEntryVar1)
        self.e1.grid()

        self.textEntryVar2 = StringVar()
        self.e2 = NumpadEntry(self,textvariable=self.textEntryVar2)
        self.e2.grid()
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("550x300")
    root.title("Monitoring Site GUI")
    app = App(root)
    app.grid()
   
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation and experimented with `grid` options such as `sticky` and `columnspan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you get in comment: you need to use `columnspan` to use space in many columns, and `sticky` (west-east) to resize button in this space.

```
    cur.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='we')
```

---

```
def createWidgets(self):

    # create and position all buttons
    btn = []

    # --- without ENTER ---

    btn_list = [
        '1',  '2',  '3',
        '4',  '5',  '6',
        '7',  '8',  '0',
        '0',  '.',  'Del'
    ]
    # Use custom generator to give us row/column positions
    for r,c,label in enumerate_row_column(btn_list, 3):
        # partial takes care of function and argument
        cmd = lambda x = label: self.click(x)
        # create the button
        cur = Button(self.top, text=label, width=5, height=3, command=cmd)
        # position the button
        cur.grid(row=r, column=c)                                              
        btn.append(cur)
        cur.grid(row=r, column=c)
        
    # --- only ENTER ---
    
    cmd = lambda x="Enter": self.click(x)
    # create the button
    cur = Button(self.top, text="Enter", width=5, height=3, command=cmd)
    # position the button
    cur.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='we')
    btn.append(cur)
```

---

[image]